# Mock || JUnit test createSOAPMessage method

Tags: java, unit-testing, soap, junit

Lost as to the best way/method in testing my createSOAPMessage method. Basically what this class is supposed to do is create a SOAP call to our central database and extract certain data in XML format. Certain keywords have been changed to protect the identity.

```
public class WebService {
        public SOAPMessage getData(String ticketNumber) throws Exception{
        //Create the SOAP Factory/Connections
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory;
        SOAPConnection soapConnection;

        //Create SOAP Connection
        soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        //Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://blahblah.asmx";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPMessage(ticketNumber), url);
        soapConnection.close();

        return soapResponse;
    }



public static SOAPMessage createSOAPMessage(String ticketNumber) throws Exception {

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://blahblah";

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();

        envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(envelope.getPrefix());
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("abc", serverURI);

        envelope.setPrefix("soapenv");
        soapHeader.setPrefix("soapenv");
        soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://blahblah.net/ExtractXML");

        //This String xml will contain the relevant data I am pulling from the db with specific column names. I've removed them as well for protection.
        String xml = "<Title>" + "<Date>" + //you get the idea.




        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));


        Element extractElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Element newDocumentElement = doc.createElementNS(serverURI, extractElement.getNodeName());

        // Set the desired namespace and prefix
        newDocumentElement.setPrefix("abc");

        Element xDoc = doc.createElement("xDoc");
        Element xDocElement = doc.createElementNS(serverURI, xDoc.getNodeName());
        xDocElement.setPrefix("abc");
        newDocumentElement.appendChild(xDocElement);

        // Copy all children
        NodeList list = extractElement.getChildNodes();
        while (list.getLength() != 0) {
            newDocumentElement.appendChild(list.item(0));
        }

        // Replace the original element
        doc.replaceChild(newDocumentElement, extractElement);

        soapBody.addDocument(doc);
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        return soapMessage;

    }
}
```

Since I'm not calling the getData method within the class itself, I don't have to create test cases for that method. The idea is to just JUnit test this class itself and create test cases for createSOAPMessage method. I just don't know how to.

Comment: Is this new code or legacy code?  Why is the method static?  (That makes it even harder to test.)  Ideally, the dependencies would be injected through a constructor, with a unit test injecting a mock of the dependency.

Comment: Agree with @AndrewS, static modifier makes methods almost "unmockable". Try to move that method to another class, make it non-static and inject the instance of that new class to the WebService. So you would easily mock it in your tests. (It's OK to slightly refactor the code for unit test purposes)